# How can I insert a line graph (ylim = 27. 30) into another diagram with 2 line graphs (ylim=0,120) without distortion?

Tags: r, ggplot2, transformation, linegraph

I need to visualize data of different character (temperature, light intensity, rel. humidity) for a kind of climate diagram. My problem, I believe, lies within the different ylims, which prevent an easy transformation to combine the graphs into one diagram. If I put in the temperature graph as in the code below, the fluctuation of the temperature becomes invisible due to the different scales of the diagram from plot_humidity.

Temperature graph inserted without transformation does not sufficiently show variation over time:
[image]

```
plot_humidity <- ggplot(df, aes(x = datetime, y = mean_humidity)) +
  geom_line(aes(y = mean_humidity, color = "Rel. humidity", group = 1), linewidth = 1) +
  geom_line(aes(y = mean_Light/100, color = "Light intensity", group = 2), linewidth = 1) +
  geom_line(aes(y = mean_Temperature, color = "Temperature", group = 3), linewidth = 1) +
  geom_ribbon(aes(ymin= mean_humidity - sd_humidity,
                  ymax= mean_humidity + sd_humidity,
                  fill = "Rel. humidity",  color = "Rel. humidity"),
              alpha=0.2, group = 1) +
  geom_ribbon(aes(ymin= (mean_Light/100) - (sd_Light/100),
                  ymax= (mean_Light/100) + (sd_Light/100),
                  fill = "Light intensity", color = "Light intensity"),
              alpha=0.2, group = 2) +
  geom_ribbon(aes(ymin= mean_Temperature - sd_Temperature,
                  ymax= mean_Temperature + sd_Temperature,
                  fill = "Temperature", color = "Temperature"),
              alpha=0.2, group = 3) +
  labs( x = "time", y = "relative humidity (in %)", color = "Variable") +
  scale_color_manual(values = c("Light intensity" = "green", "Temperature" = "red", "Rel. humidity" = "blue")) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("Light intensity" = "green", "Temperature" = "red", "Rel. humidity" = "blue")) +
  scale_x_datetime(breaks = "1 hour", date_labels = "%H",
                   limits = as.POSIXct(strptime(c("2022-12-23 01:00:00", "2022-12-24 01:00:00"),
                                                format = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")),
                   expand = c(0, 0)) +
  theme(axis.line.y.left =  element_line( color = "blue"),
        axis.text.y.left = element_text(color = "blue"),
        plot.margin = margin(10, 10, 10, 30)) +
  guides(fill = "none") +
  scale_y_continuous(limits = c(), sec.axis = sec_axis(~ . * 100, name = "light intensity (in lux)")) +
  theme(axis.text.y.right = element_text(color = "green"),
        axis.line.y.right = element_line(color = "green"))



  plot <- wrap_elements(get_plot_component(plot_temperature, "ylab-l")) +
  wrap_elements(get_y_axis(plot_temperature)) +
  plot_humidity +
  plot_layout(widths = c( 3, 1, 40))
```

Instead of the red graph in the diagram above, I want to have it look like below and overlap with the other graphs.

[image: single temperature graph]

```
plot_temperature <- ggplot(df, aes(x = datetime, y = mean_Temperature)) +
  geom_line(aes(y= mean_Temperature, color = "Temperature"), linewidth = 1) +
  geom_ribbon(aes(ymin= mean_Temperature - sd_Temperature,
                  ymax= mean_Temperature + sd_Temperature,
                  fill = "Temperature", color = "Temperature"), alpha = 0.2) +
  labs(y = "mean temperature (in °C) +/- standard deviation") +
  scale_color_manual(values = "red") +
  theme(axis.line.y.left =  element_line( color = "red"),
        axis.text.y.left = element_text(color = "red"),) +
  scale_x_datetime(breaks = "1 hour", date_labels = "%H",
                   limits = as.POSIXct(strptime(c("2022-12-23 01:00:00", "2022-12-24 01:00:00"),
                                                format = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")),
                   expand = c(0, 0))
```

My original plan was to use ggplot and wrap_elements to fuse the different parts of the diagrams (y-axis, ylab, geom_line, geom_ribbon) into one diagram. This is not a problem for the light intensity graph, but the temperature graph is a problem.
I can´t just transform the data, or can I? And I haven´t found a way to extract geom_line and geom_ribbon from the single temperature diagram to lay it over plot_humidity, but I would be fine with that as well, if there is no more elegant solution to it.

Is there anything obvious that I am missing? Since I am still learning about R and the work that includes this figure is my first big effort, I appreciate any tips you can give me!

EDIT:
[Here is my df](https://wetransfer.com/downloads/dcab332ab8b4d2eaa30c5b3394656f8620240214171021/23c983)

Comment: This is tricky to replicate without some data, would you be able to share some workable data to use? I think the solution would involve transforming your temperature data and reverse-transforming the axis, in the same way you've done for the right-hand y axis to make the units cover the same range as the other plot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you try transforming your values in plot 1 and back-transforming your scales in plot 2 (with same limits) then this should work:

```r
library(tidyverse)

file_path <- "datalogger.csv"

df <- read_csv(file_path) |>
  mutate(
    mean_Temperature = Durchschnitt_Temperatur,
    mean_Light = Durchschnitt_Licht,
    mean_humidity = Durchschnitt_Feuchtigkeit,
    sd_Temperature = sd_Temperatur,
    sd_Light = sd_Licht,
    sd_humidity = sd_Feuchtigkeit
  )

g1 <- df |>
  ggplot(aes(time)) +
  geom_line(aes(y = mean_humidity, colour = "Rel. humidity")) +
  geom_line(aes(y = mean_Light / 100, colour = "Light intensity")) +
  geom_line(aes(y = (mean_Temperature - 27) * 40, colour = "Temperature")) +
  geom_ribbon(aes(ymin= mean_humidity - sd_humidity,
                  ymax= mean_humidity + sd_humidity,
                  fill = "Rel. humidity",  color = "Rel. humidity"),
              alpha=0.2, group = 1) +
  geom_ribbon(aes(ymin= (mean_Light/100) - (sd_Light/100),
                  ymax= (mean_Light/100) + (sd_Light/100),
                  fill = "Light intensity", color = "Light intensity"),
              alpha=0.2, group = 2) +
  geom_ribbon(aes(ymin= (mean_Temperature - 27 - sd_Temperature) * 40,
                  ymax= (mean_Temperature - 27 + sd_Temperature) * 40,
                  fill = "Temperature", color = "Temperature"),
              alpha=0.2, group = 3) +
  scale_y_continuous(
    sec.axis = sec_axis(~ . * 100, name = "light intensity (in lux)"),
    limits = c(-10, 120)
  ) +
  scale_color_manual(values = c(
    "Light intensity" = "green",
    "Temperature" = "red",
    "Rel. humidity" = "blue"
  ), 
  aesthetics = c("fill", "colour")) +
  labs( x = "time", y = "relative humidity (in %)", color = "Variable") +
  theme(
    axis.line.y.left =  element_line(color = "blue"),
    axis.text.y.left = element_text(color = "blue"),
    plot.margin = margin(10, 10, 10, 30),
    axis.text.y.right = element_text(color = "green"),
    axis.line.y.right = element_line(color = "green"),
    text = element_text(size = 8)
  ) +
  guides(fill = "none")


g2 <- df |>
  ggplot(aes(time, mean_Temperature)) +
  geom_line(aes(colour = "Temperature")) +
  theme(
    axis.line.y.left =  element_line(color = "red"),
    axis.text.y.left = element_text(color = "red"),
    text = element_text(size = 8)
  ) +
  scale_y_continuous(
    sec.axis = sec_axis(~ (. / 40) +27 , name = "Temperature"),
    position = "right",
    limits = c(-10, 120)
  )

library(patchwork)
library(cowplot)

wrap_elements(get_plot_component(g2, "ylab-l")) +
  wrap_elements(get_y_axis(g2, position = "left")) +
  g1 +
  plot_layout(widths = c(3, 1, 40))
```

[image]

Comment: I tried to compile your example, but unfortunately it didn´t work out for me. R didn´t want to have the "transform" function in sec_axis. However, I also tried to adapt your ideas into my code, but that also only worked not quite as I expected. I cannot get a grip of the transformed secondary y-axis for wrap_elements and geom_ribbon gets compressed due to the different scale limits in g1, respectively plot_humidity. 
I provided my dataframe for you. I hope, that helps a bit better.

Comment: `transform` is a recent change of arguments from the former `trans`, apologies for this! Have edited out and should now work. Have used your data now too. That seems to be plotting all the things in the right places. Temperature has been plotted as ranging from ~40 to ~80 to size up to a level comparable to humidity, then the axis borrowed from the other plot labels this correctly as ~28 to ~29. The identical limits across both plots ensure no further stretching or compressing so that ticks and datapoints line up.

Comment: Thanks a million! That helped a LOT and I could now get what I wanted! Have a wonderful day!